# Populate UITableView with custom objects?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am unsuccessfully trying to populate a UITable from a NSMutableArray that contains a custom object.

My Student object

```
Student {
    NSString name,
    int age
}
```

In my UITableView's controller I have implemented a method that displays the row's content:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
{
    // there is more code here
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

But the above does not work for an object inside an array.

Should my Student class implement a method that returns a String representation of the object? And then how can I display the content of the NSMutableArray in the UITableView.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objectAtIndex should be a Student object, so you need to get its properties -- assuming that name and age are properties, you should be able to reference them with [(Student *)[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]; and the corresponding one for age.